# Android best practises: sharing data between fragments in ViewPager

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-viewpager, realm

**The case:** I use [guide from androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) to implement two tabs that by one activity. First one - list with complex objects in recyclerview, second - map with elements from this list. As DB I use SQLite but I'm going to migrate on nice and cozy Realm.

In SQLite case general approach which looks appropriate is to make list item object **Parcelable** and then use bundle to transfer data from activity to fragments. 
One call to the database, seems legit.

But in case of Realm I cannot use **Parcelable** because it requires getters/setters methods only.

What is the best way in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only send an ID of the object you want to display and then fetch the object in the fragment as described here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#intents

Answer (score 1):

I belive you can make your model class implement Parcelable, it won't affect anything related to realm, you'll use the getters/setters along with the CREATOR object.

Another option is to use realm [Parceler](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#parceler)  library, as mentioned in the docs, it generates the code required to make the objects parcelable so that you can pass them between activities or fragments.